# Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got safe/sanitized HTML saved in a DB table.

How can I have this HTML content written out in a Razor view?

It always escapes characters like `<` and ampersands to `&amp;`.

Comment: To save people like me trying to do this with  with anonymous types in dynamically typed views, where this won't work - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31306368/957950) to my more-specific question. Although using this approach with a strongly-typed view is still better if your situation allows.

Answer (score 688):

Supposing your content is inside a string named `mystring`...

You can use:

```
@Html.Raw(mystring)
```

Alternatively you can convert your string to [`HtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx) or any other type that implements `IHtmlString` in model or directly inline and use regular `@`:

```
@{ var myHtmlString = new HtmlString(mystring);}
@myHtmlString
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Helped me finish a little task I was learning. :) However I'm using the latest version of MVC3 and so far no Html.Raw :(

Comment: Hi Sergio. I'm using MVC 3 and i'm using the Raw method properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I'm still learning MVC 3 and this was eluding me.

Comment: @Lorenzo, +1 I'm using the latest MVC 3 with `razor` syntax and `Html.Raw` is definitely available to me.

Comment: Is there anything like `@Html.RawFor(m => m.HtmlField)`?

Comment: Lorenzo, I've updated answer to remove mentioning of MVC Beta as it was some years ago. Feel free to revert/change.

Comment: Say I was to define a global variable in razor, and then use @html.Raw(  on this variable because I want to define some markup in it and render on view.   Is there a way someone can set a value to a Razor variable from the url? I just want to make sure this isn't vulnerable to XSS through URL injection.. Thanks!

Comment: `@{ var myHtmlString = new HtmlString(mystring);}
@myHtmlString`
Worked

Comment: Please note for Core Razor pages, `HtmlString` requires `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html`

Answer (score 76):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 You should do something like this:

```
// Say you have a bit of HTML like this in your controller:
ViewBag.Stuff = "<li>Menu</li>"
//  Then you can do this in your view:
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Stuff)
```

Comment: I prefer this method because HTML.Raw blows up if the passed string is null.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clean!

Answer (score 76):

You can use

```
@{ WriteLiteral("html string"); }
```

Comment: This was awesome for me, was using Razor within a Hangfire app to send emails... `Html.Raw()` doesn't work there

Comment: 1 for WriteLiteral

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes it can be tricky to use raw html. Mostly because of XSS vulnerability. If that is a concern, but you still want to use raw html, you can encode the scary parts.

```
@Html.Raw("(<b>" + Html.Encode("<script>console.log('insert')</script>" + "Hello") + "</b>)")
```

Results in

```
(<b>&lt;script&gt;console.log('insert')&lt;/script&gt;Hello</b>)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put your string into viewdata in controller like this :

```
 ViewData["string"] = DBstring;
```

And then call that viewdata in view like this :

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["string"].ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using `@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Stuff)`
 as suggested by Dommer, I suggest you to also use [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library as suggested phill http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx

It encodes almost all the possible XSS attack string.

Answer (score 0):

Complete example for using template functions in RazorEngine (for email generation, for example):

```
@model SomeModel
@{
    Func<PropertyChangeInfo, object> PropInfo =
        @<tr class="property">
            <td>
                @item.PropertyName                
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <small class="old">@item.OldValue</small>
                <small class="new">@item.CurrentValue</small>                
            </td>
        </tr>;
}

<body>

@{ WriteLiteral(PropInfo(new PropertyChangeInfo("p1", @Model.Id, 2)).ToString()); }

</body>
```