# How would I tell a browser to render a string, not display it

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, viewengine

I have this extension method I created and it returns a string of all the categories in my database as hyperlinks. Great!

```
@Html.MyMenu()
```

The problem is that the links are being displayed as text and not rendered as hyperlinks.

When viewing the source code I see:

```
<div id="menucontainer">

                &lt;a href=&quot;/Anuncio/Electronics&quot;&gt;Electronics&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Anuncio/Clothes&quot;&gt;Clothes&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Anuncio/Domestic&quot;&gt;Domestic&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Anuncio/Garden&quot;&gt;Garden&lt;/a&gt;

            </div>
```

I think I may be wrong but I remember that in MVC2 (using the default view engine) you had:

```
<%: this is rendered, right? %>
```

Or am I mistaken? Anyways, I'm using MVC3 and the Razor engine. Thanks a lot for your help guys. I'm really enjoying learning as much as I can about this.

Comment: Please let me know if you need to see the code in the View. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor escapes HTML by default.

To avoid that, please do something like this:

[Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/asp-net-mvc-razor-output-html-string-non-escaped)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem. Here's my solution: @(new HtmlString(@Html.MyMenu()))

Comment: But you could also make `Html.MyMenu()` return a `HtmlString`! I guess it would be better... Unless you need it to return a regular string (for reusing it somewhere else, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

In RC2 a new method called @HTml.Raw should to this.

Or you can change MyMenu to return HtmlString or MvcString rather than just string.

Comment: I can't find this method on MSDN and Google returns no results. Can you share a link?

Comment: @sergio sure! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/asp-net-mvc-razor-output-html-string-non-escaped/4282073#4282073

Answer (score 0):

well your extension method should be returning an `MvcHtmlString` in order to properly display on your page using the `<%: %>` If it returns a string, all angle brackets and other html special characters will be html-encoded.

Comment: I only mentioned the brackets to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. You can't use the brackets of MVC2 on the Razor engine.

Answer (score 0):

RC2 supports @Html.Raw() to output raw HTML

From [Scott Guthrie's RC2 anouncement](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)

> With RC2 we are adding a Html.Raw() helper method that you can use to explicitly indicate that you do not want to HTML encode your output, and instead want to render the content “as-is”