# .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Why does `.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")` give this result:

```
asdasd<br />waahahahaha<br />asdadsa<br />multiline<br /><br /><br />asdad
```

Comment: probably because you had a new line character in those places.

Comment: what i want is for the <br /> to go away and get the next line down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because there are more than one new line between "multiline" and "asdad".

**Example**

```
var someText = string.Format("First line{0}Second line{0}Multiple line breaks{0}{0}{0}some text", Environment.NewLine);

var html = someText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

html will now look like this:

```
First line<br />Second line<br/>Multiple line breaks<br /><br /><br />some text
```

**Edit**

In your case your web page will display the `<br />` in the web-browser and not create a new line because it encodes the html output.

What you will need to do is use HtmlString, try this:

```
<div class="display-field">
    <%: new HtmlString(Model.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) %>
</div>
```

Also see this thread here on StackOverflow talking about ["ASP.NET MVC Razor - output HTML string non escaped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/asp-net-mvc-razor-output-html-string-non-escaped).

Comment: but im using <div class="display-field"><%: Model.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")%></div>

Comment: @paul, `Model.Body` most likely contains multiple NewLines between `mutiline` and `asdad`.

Comment: nope...but when i view the page source its showing that <br /> is now &lt;br /&gt;

Comment: @paul, Ohhh I get your problem now.. Hold on, I will update my answer.

Comment: @paul, It was a typo, there should be a `:` there as well. Updated again!

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: You can use a {x} multiple times. In your example you could have simply used {0} all the time

Comment: @citronas, good point. I've edited the answer. If you see things like this, feel free to edit answers.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: I have do get used to the idea, that I now have the edit functionality ;)

Comment: @citronas, everyone can edit, just needs to be approved by users with 10k rep and above.

Comment: I was looking for a solution in web forms. "new HtmlString" works like a charme: <%#: new HtmlString(Item.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) %>