# How to write html field on asp.net MVC3 Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've a String field on my model that contains an html value, my problem is that when I place the code to render this field on my view it will be entirely reconverted to html, and the final result is a big string with html characters escaped...

```
@field //= "<div>"
```

renders

```
 &lt ;div&gt ;
```

How can i override this behavior and force it to write the html unescaped on my field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/writing-outputting-html-strings-unescaped)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `Html.Raw` helper:

```
@Html.Raw(field)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use @Html.Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(field)
```