# Output in unicode from ViewBag

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3, unicode, viewbag

From my controller I'm assigning either an up arrow (&uarr) or down arrow (&darr) with unicode to a ViewBag, that I want to use in the view.

Of course I want the output to become an arrow, but that doesn't work and the output becomes a string (e.g. &uarr).

**controller:**

```
...
ViewBag.Arrow = "&uarr;";
...
```

**view:**

```
...
ViewBag.Arrow <br /> // <--- &uarr;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Arrow)` than `@Html.Raw(...`. See my answer here for the reason why: [Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/asp-net-mvc-razor-output-html-string-non-escaped/5084995#5084995)

Answer (score 2):

You must output using `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Arrow)`, this way your string will rendered verbatim, and not encoded (which is what the issue is).

Outputting using simply `@ViewBag.Arrow` results in asp.net mvc encoding your value for safe html output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.Arrow);
```