# How to render HTML string in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

On my main page, I have the code `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial1.cshtml");}`, and on my Partial, I have an HTML string:

```
@{ 
    // The string is actually dynamic, not static. This is here for simplicity
    string abc="<div class=\"error\">abc</div>";
} 
@abc
```

I want to output `abc` with some CSS error styles, but I actually got `<div class="error">abc</div>` - of course, no styles there. How do I make it interpreted as HTML source code and not a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/asp-net-mvc-razor-output-html-string-non-escaped

Comment: What's wrong with `<div class="error">abc</div>`?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can use the `Html.Raw()` method for that.

Comment: This was absolutely amazing. Tip if you have an .html file you want to render instead use: @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(<htmlpath>)))

Comment: This is a dangerous answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Say I was to define a global variable in razor, and then use @html.Raw(  on this variable because I want to define some markup in it and render on view.   Is there a way someone can set a value to a Razor variable from the url? I just want to make sure this isn't vulnerable to XSS through URL injection.. Thanks!

Comment: @user1794106 As long as you don't fill the variable from parts of the request, then no. Razor view variables are entirely evaluated on the server in a local scope.

Comment: this needs to be updated to warn the user of the potential security issues it can create!

Comment: @Drakoumel And what potential security issues might that be? This method is not more dangerous than any other method that creates output.

Comment: Still relevant today 

Answer (score 2):

And if you are using model in your view than use:

```
@model YourApp.Models.YourModel
....

@Html.Raw(@Model.NameOfYourProperty)
```