# Render string to html in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

A similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548797/how-to-render-html-string-in-asp-net-mvc) but the answer did not solve my problem below.

How can I render a string to html?  Basically, I need to pass a string to the view that has an "a" tag definition in it.  What I want is to render it as an actual html link that is clickable.

View Model (simplified):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyLink { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller (simplified):

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

    model.MyLink = "&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;http://www.google.com&lt;/a&gt;"

    return View(model);
}
```

In View (at first line):

```
@model MyNamespace.ViewModel.MyViewModel
```

Then below, these html markups (1st lines after the numbers) displays the results (2nd lines).  But none of them are actual links that you can click on.

```
1
@Model.MyLink
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;http://www.google.com&lt;/a&gt;

2
<pre>@Html.Raw(@Model.MyLink)</pre>
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>

3
@Html.Encode(@Html.Raw(@Model.MyLink))
&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.google.com&amp;quot;&amp;gt;http://www.google.com&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;

4 
@Html.Encode(@Model.MyLink)
result same as #3.
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "pass a string to the view".  Your method uses an IActionResult and should be returning a view.  If you don't want to return a view then you may want to use a json response back to an ajax call, then use jQuery to append the new html.

Comment: Sorry to not be clear.  The method is returning a view (model).  This is what I am using in the view (@Model).  I would edit my question if I can only figure out how lol.

Comment: Well, the *recommended* thing to do is just pass the data via the model and have the view itself render the html.  But, you could pass the string into a javascript variable  and then use jQuery to add it to the DOM.  I really don't recommend this but it would technically work.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clear what the controller is returning to the view.  Can you please include an example of what you are suggesting regarding the jQuery?

Comment: Inside of some <script tags, put var myAnchor = "@Model.MyLink";   Then use $('#myDiv').append(myAnchor);   That would append the anchor to something with an id of 'myDiv'.   Need to emphasize that while this should work (may need some tinkering) it is really not a good solution... It is very odd to do things this way.  You *should* have the razor create it instead.

Comment: I tried it, but it resulted to the same result as #1.  It still did not render as an actual link.

Comment: Can you use the actual characters < instead of the url encoded versions?

Comment: I'm open for the better solutions!  How would I do this then "You should have the razor create it instead."?

Comment: Try the decodeURI() javascript function.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Comment: That data is coming from the database.  I can probably replace the string to use the actual characters, but it is trickier as I may not catch everything that needs to be replaced.

Comment: I used the decodeURI but it produced the same result as #1.  var myAnchor = "@Model.MyLink"; $('#MyDiv').append(decodeURI(myAnchor));

Comment: Try #2 using what is talked about here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1108363.aspx?unescape+decodeURI+Javascript+equivalent+in+NET   Also try using this in the controller before you save the variable onto the model.  Some combination of that should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render HTML string in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548797/how-to-render-html-string-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @nurdyguy. I cannot add a comment to your answer below, so I will just put my comment here ==> Oh okay, this is what you meant.  I really cannot do this because the string from the database is not the link value itself but the entire html element for the anchor tag.  I probably can parse it, which might also not be a good way, so I can take advantage of the razor engine.  But I want to see first if there is a way I can just render the string as an actual html element.

Comment: @MelanciaUK.  I saw that question.  But as you can see above, the answer to that question with using Html.raw did not work for my case.

Comment: @MelanciaUK.  I've updated my question so it will link to the question you listed and to clarify that the answer there did not solve my problem.  Please remove the downvote.

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate. It doesn't mean I've downvoted it. Votes are anonymous by the way.

Comment: @nurdyguy. I'm new to MVC so do not know exactly yet how to make the "Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject" for decodeURI accessible in the controller.  I'll add comments here as soon as I have something to work.  Thanks for your tips!

Comment: @MelanciaUK.  Okay, gotcha.

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question, can you please explain why?  At least I would know why for next time I will ask another question.

Comment: Use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(url); in the controller and then Html.Raw in the view.  I got that working on my local test.

Comment: [Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/writing-outputting-html-strings-unescaped)

Comment: [Rendering HTML as HTML in Razor](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=2218)

Comment: Okay, I will try to figure out first how I can make "HttpUtility" accessible to the controller.  I tried adding "using System.Web" but that did not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the controller use

```
model.MyLink = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(url);
```

then in the view use

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MyLink)
```

The first converts it to use

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!  It looks like the WebUtility.HtmlDecode is the equivalent of HttpUtility.HtmlDecode for MVC 6 (or ASP.NET Core) RC1.  This is what worked for me:  In Controller => model.MyLink = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(model.MyLink);  and in View => @Html.Raw(@Model.MyLink)

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working!  Sorry for all of the extra drawn-out comments.  I misunderstood the original question so at first I was way off but at least we got it done in the end.

Comment: No problem.  I probably also should have made it more clear.  In the end, it was your solution that solved it!  Thanks again.