# SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant when loading string

Tags: c#, javascript, string, format

Hello I have this code in my `ASP.NET Razor v2 cshtml` file that should load `string` into this paragraph the variable is from `c# list of strings` but when the `string` that is loaded contains something like this:

```
+ "<p>"+'Rejv&#237;zsk&#225; 113 79001 Jesen&#237;k'+"</p>"
```

I get this JavaScript critical error: `SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant`

The program fails because some character escaped my `ending quotation mar` `'`

Actually the code looks like this:

```
"<p>"+'@string.Format(serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"
```

serviceDescription is list of strings that may containt whatever value that can escape my `'` character.

May I please know how to correct this?

This code is used in adjusting `InfoWindow in Google API`

So far I tried and non of these method worked:

```
  + "<p>"+' @string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"

  + "<p>"+'@string.Format(serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"

  + "<p>"+'@string.Format("{0}", @Html.Raw(serviceDescription[i]))'+"</p>"

  + "<p>"+' @(new HtmlString(serviceDescription[i]))'+"</p>" 

  + "<p>"+' @Html.Raw(serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"

  + ' @Html.Raw("<p>"+@serviceDescription[i]+"</p>")'

  "<p>" @Html.Raw(String.Format(serviceDescription[i]))+"</p>"

  + @(new HtmlString("<p>"+serviceDescription[i]+"</p>"))
```

My whole InfoWindow code:

```
  var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map
        });
        /*   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{binary data}" />   */


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            var $infoWindowContent = $("<div style='line-height:1.35;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;width: 200px'><h3>" + '@serviceTitle[i].ToString()'
                + '</h3><img src=@string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", serviceImgMIME[i], Convert.ToBase64String(serviceImgBinary[i])) style="width: 100%;max-height: 100%"/>'


                + "<p>"+ @Html.Raw(String.Format("{0}",serviceDescription[i]))+"</p>" // this is the line that causes me pain
                + "Web: " + "<a href="+'http://@string.Format("{0}", serviceLink[i])'+">"+'@serviceLink[i].ToString()'+"</a>"
                + "<br>"
                + "Kontakt: "+ "<a href="+'mailto:@serviceContact[i].ToString()'+">"+'@serviceContact[i].ToString()'+"</a>"
                + "<p>"+"Lze platit v: "+"<b>"+'@serviceIDCryptoCur[i].ToString()'+"</b>"+"</p>"
                + @switch (serviceIDCryptoCur[i])
                  {
                      case "BTC": 
                <text>
                '<img height="20" width"20" src="~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png">'
            </text>
                          break;
                      case "LTC": 
                <text>
            '<img height="20" width"20" src="~/Content/ikonky/ltcSmall.png">'
            </text>
                          break;
                      case "BTC,LTC":
        <text>
            '<img height="20" width"20"  src="~/Content/ikonky/ltcSmall.png"> <img height="20" width"20"  src="~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png">' 
        </text>
                          break;
                      default:
        <text>
                '<img height="20" width"20"  src="~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png">'
        </text>
                          break;
                  }

                + "</div>");
            info.setContent($infoWindowContent[0]);
            info.open(map, this);
        });
```

Comment: Just a guess but I thought `string.Format` was supposed to be like: `@string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", serviceDescription[1])`. If not, my bad ...

Comment: What is it? C#, Java or Javascript?

Comment: Cshtml file. Using Javascript in google maps API

Comment: @TimVermaelen I tried but still got the same Javascript critical error.

Comment: How do you know `'` is escaped? I dont see anything like that. What is the Javascript critical error? `'Rejv&#237;zsk&#225; 113 79001 Jesen&#237;k'` is a valid JavaScript string.

Comment: @YK1 `SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant`

Comment: and my `1` should be an `i` ... too late to edit it

Comment: if you want render raw string see [HtmlHelper.Raw Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: In JavaScript this could be solved by a function [decodeHtmlEntity](https://gist.github.com/CatTail/4174511) or a jQuery example: `$("<div/>").html(s).text();`

Comment: Does this error occur with the example string you've shown? Have you tested with other values whether it works? Error might be on some other line. Could you show us the full loop code?

Comment: @YK1 I tried to replace that string and everything worked fine. I really thing that it is escaping my end quotation mark.

Comment: Only back-slash can escape `'` -  which is not there in your sample string.

Comment: Maybe just check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/writing-outputting-html-strings-unescaped)

Comment: @TimVermaelen I tried to edit my code a bit but still same result. May you please check my edited question whether I formated correctly? Thank you for your time.

Comment: try @Html.Raw(string.Format("<p>{0}</p>",serviceDescription[i]))

Comment: @Grundy still got same error.

Comment: I feel problem is somewhere else. Please could you show code around the line `"<p>"+'@string.Format(serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"`

Comment: @YK1 I uploaded my code.

Comment: `serviceDescription[i]` is string?

Comment: Yes, it is `list of strings`.

Comment: Can you check in you final HTML output, what is the values for the line above the one you mentioned? I am suspecting the `<img src ..` but not sure. Can you add quotes around `src`?

Comment: @YK1 I think <img src> is ok because it is formated like `string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}"` also I'm not sure how to correctly quote the `img src` may you please sent code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `@string.Format("\"data:{0};base64,{1}\""`

Comment: @YK1 Still got the same error even after editing the img src and using `"<p>"+'@string.Format(serviceDescription[i])'+"</p>"`

Comment: difficult to figure. Another thing you can check is whether any of your data value like `@serviceTitle[i].ToString()` could contain a single quote?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42154/discussion-between-marek-and-yk1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need move this string generating to functions like this

```
@functions{
    string infowindow(string title, string imgMime, string imgBase64, string descr, string link, string kontakt, string crypt){
        var result = @"<div style='line-height:1.35;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;width: 200px'>
                <h3>{0}</h3>
                <img src='data:{1};base64,{2}' style='width: 100%;max-height: 100%' />
                <p>{3}</p>
                Web: <a href='{4}'>{4}</a><br />
                Kontakt: <a href='mailto:{5}'>{5}</a>
                <p>Lze platit v: <b>{6}</b></p>";
                switch (crypt)
                {
                    case "LTC":
                        result += "<img height='20' width='20' src='~/Content/ikonky/ltcSmall.png'>";
                    break;
                    case "BTC":
                        result += "<img height='20' width='20' src='~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png'>";
                    break;
                    case "BTC,LTC":
                        result += "<img height='20' width='20' src='~/Content/ikonky/ltcSmall.png'> <img height='20' width='20' src='~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png'>";
                    break;
                    default:
                        result += "<img height='20' width='20' src='~/Content/ikonky/btcSmall.png'>";
                    break;
            }
        result += "</div>";
        return result.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var $infoWindowContent = $("@Html.Raw(infowindow(serviceTitle[i],serviceImgMIME[i], Convert.ToBase64String(serviceImgBinary[i]),serviceDescription[i],serviceLink[i],serviceContact[i],serviceIDCryptoCur[i]))")
```