# HTML in C# Resource File

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building an ASP.NET MVC website where I keep all of my localized string in a `.resx` resource file. However, if I try to embed any formatting or Unicode characters, I have a problem.

Example resource file [EN_US.resx]:

```
Key                       Value
=================================================================================
INTRO_COLLEGE             This is a <strong>really</strong> nice college&hellip;
```

Example view:

```
<p>@EN_US.INTRO_COLLEGE</p>
```

My problem is, any HTML formatting or special characters are literally printed as they are written in the resource file, like this:

```
This is a <strong>really</strong> nice college&hellip;
```

How can I include HTML formatting and Unicode characters in a `.resx` file such that they are not automatically escaped when it is printed out?

Comment: Yep, I found this out AFTER I posted this. lol

Comment: That always seems to be the way.  The search on related works better than the question search.

Comment: Did you try any of the methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/writing-outputting-html-strings-unescaped)