# How to render HTML data from XML

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have an XML file having elements like this

```
<component name="component1">
<title><![CDATA[Title <span>(Subtitle)</span>]]></title>
</component>
```

I want to render the title in an HTML page. I can read the title element and when I am rendering it in the HTML page(in browser) I am getting as `Title<span>(Subtitle)</span>` in the page. In the HTML source it is as `Title&lt;span&gt;(Subtitle)&lt;/span&gt;`

How can I overcome this.

I am using C# for reading the XML data

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("pathofdocument");
XmlNodeList nodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/list/components/componet");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
 string title = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code that is putting the XML data into the HTML.

Comment: I am using C# for reading from the XML

Comment: You need to show us the relevant code (it would be a good idea to read http://sscce.org/ ) and not just tell us what programming language you are using.

Comment: After your latest edit, you've shown us the code that reads the data from the XML, but not the code that generates the HTML from it.

Comment: I will put the title in a ViewBag and put the ViewBag in the html tag. The edited code is a controller code and I will place the ViewBag from the controller in View code. Hope you understand what I am saying

Comment: Show how you put the string from ViewBag in the html tag then. That's closely related to why you got the string escaped, and how to fix it : [Writing/outputting HTML strings unescaped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281424/writing-outputting-html-strings-unescaped)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use  [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)