# How to use Razor display template to convert string to html string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm new to razor and display templates so please correct me where I'm wrong. I'm working with a string that contains HTML. If I try [converting it directly to a HtmlString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4282073/4896260), my Ajax form refuses to submit. As a workaround I tried to use Display templates with the goal of achieving something like this

My `@foreach` loop contains this

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => myModel.myString, "HtmlString")
```

My DisplayTemplate contains this

HtmlString.cshtml

```
@model String

@{
    new HtmlString(@Model);
}
```

So if `myString = "<ul><li>my text</li></ul>"`

I would like my ajax form to display

- my text

What I have now doesn't work and returns nothing. Please help with what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@Html.Raw()` like;

`@Html.Raw(Model.myString)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean to use `@Html.Raw(Model.myString)` in `HtmlString.cshtml` ? Because I tried using this in my View and the Ajax form refused to submit.

Comment: @usr4896260. Using `Html.Raw()` is correct. But this has nothing to do with your Ajax form. If you have a problem with that, then you should show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor modifications to your code. Please test and implement.

In your `HtmlString.cshtml` file, replace your code with the following. This is a `partial view` that is being called in a `foreach` loop and is passed a `string` value that contains `HTML`. `@Html.Raw` is used to displayed the HTML as HTML:

```
@model String

@Html.Raw(Model)
```

Your view will receive a list of strings that is passed from your controller's action method. Each string contains the HTML:

```
@model List<string>

@foreach (var s in Model)
{
     @Html.Partial("HtmlString", s)
}
```

This is the data that I used to test your scenario. The HTML that is outputted is correct:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod1()
{
     List<string> strings = new List<string>();

     strings.Add("<ul><li>my text</li></ul>");
     strings.Add("<ul><li>my text</li></ul>");

     return View(strings);
}
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
<ul><li>my text</li></ul><ul><li>my text</li></ul>
```

I hope that I understood your question correctly?